# How to bind parameters to InfluxDB Python client query

Tags: python, influxdb

How can I bind *query* parameters to an InfluxDB query using the Python client?

For example, I want the results of a query filtered by the `InfluxDb` tag "my_tag": `some_id=5` `SELECT * FROM "foobar" WHERE ("my_tag"=some_id);`

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host=my_host,port=my_port)
client.switch_database(database=my_database)

def get_results_by_id(my_id):
    results = client.query(
        query='SELECT * FROM "foobar" WHERE ("my_tag" = id)',
        params={"id": my_id}
    )
    ...
)
```

Getting zero results with this. Obviously, I can just use a string formatter, but there must be a way to do it with the Influx API.

Answer (score 3):

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host=my_host,port=my_port)
client.switch_database(database=my_database)

def get_results_by_id(my_id):
    results = client.query(
        query='SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE my_tag=$my_tag;',
        params={"my_tag": my_id}
    )
    ...
)
```

Comment: It's a good style to also use a few words to explain what you did to make it work.